# Is it possibile to check if there is a new line or not?

Tags: java, selenium, junit, automated-tests

I am trying to automate some test with Selenium. There is one problem occurred:

Is there a way to check the amount of elements per row?
I want to ensure that after 6 elements is a new line.

Example:
[image]

Maybe someone can help me. Thanks!

Comment: What does the HTML look like? What does your code look like? Where is your complete, minimal, reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a web table then just count no of column with iterating rows. Like start from 0th row, count no of columns then iterate each row and count no of columns.

Is it possible to access your application, then can I can try from my side.